# Show that the normed space $(l^1, ||.||_1)$ is complete.

Tags: analysis, normed-spaces

I am thinking to start off by saying that $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy in $l_1$, so for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $N$ such that $\sum^\infty_{k=1}\mid x^n_k - x^m_k\mid <\epsilon^2$ for $n$, $m>N$.

For every fixed $k_0$, we have $\mid x^n_{k_0} - x^m_{k_0}\mid<\epsilon $ for $n$, $m>N$.

So, $\{x^n_{k_0}\}$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb{K}$ and converges to $a_{k_0}$.

Now, we will show that $(a_k-x_k)\in l^1$ becomes $(a_k)\in l^1$ because $l^1$ is a vector space.

So for any $M\in N$, $\sum^M_{k=1}\mid a_k-x^n_k\mid=\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\sum^M_{k=1}\mid x^M_k-x^n_k\mid \leq \epsilon$ for $n>N$.

By letting $M\rightarrow\infty$, we say
$$\sum^M_{k=1}\mid a_k-x^M_k\mid\leq \epsilon^2,$$
and so $a-x_m\in l^1$.

Therefore, $||a-x_n||_1\leq\epsilon$ and $x_n\rightarrow a$ in $l^1$.

Is this correct? I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: In $l^1$, there are no squares, you used the wrong norm. But the argument is in principle right, just use the $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_1$ norm instead of the $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_2$-norm.

Comment: Are you working in $l_1$ or $l_2$?

Comment: I should be working in $l_1$, I have attempted to amend the errors, would it be correct now?